# Turning off Labels using ArcPy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, labeling, arcgis-10.8

I am outputting a set of maps with various layers and baselayers. On some of these I need to turn off the labels to reduce the noise and to see the baselayer with no obstructions.

I cant seem to figure out a way to turn off the labels for only the selected output maps.
I have tried multiple variations of this code to no avail

```
lyrList = ['fields']
for lyr in lyrList:
     if lyr.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
          lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, lyr, df)[0]
          lyr.showLables = False
          arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

edit: to show lyrList is strings

Comment: Please share the lyrList. If it is a collection of layer objects vs a collection of strings (layer names) determines the script that follows.

Comment: Please start your [code snippet](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/4312) with `import arcpy` (unless your running it from the Python Window, which does that automatically).

Comment: What errors (if any) did you get when running that code?

Comment: @Keggering i added the lyrList I am using. I have tried many variations of this list. I'm not a programmer so I'm basically just stumbling blind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Layer](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm#P_GUID-A1071A05-599A-4662-8354-4F676BA87878) class of arcpy.mapping does not have a property named `showLables` [sic] but it does have one named `showLabels`.  I would change the code that you have presented to be:

```
for lyr in lyrList:
     if lyr.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
          lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, lyr, df)[0]
          lyr.showLabels = False  # spelling of property name corrected here
arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

In addition to correcting the spelling of the property name, I also moved `arcpy.RefreshActiveView()` outside of loop so that the display only needs to be refreshed once, instead of once for every layer that supports label classes.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect `lyrList` is a collection of name-strings (e.g. `lyrList = ["Layer1", "Layer2",]`). If this is the case, the string-type item doesn't work here `if lyr.supports("LABELCLASSES"):`.

Alternatively, `lyrList` is a collection layer Objects (e.g. `lyrList = [<map layer u'SomeLayerName'>, <map layer u'SomeOtherLayerName'>]`
, then redefining a lyr object with `lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, lyr, df)[0]` doesn't work, as the "lyr" parameter should be a string (even if it worked, it's redundant).

Here is a snippet to ellaborate:

```
import arcpy

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"CURRENT")### "CURRENT" or some path, e.g. r"C:\Project\Project.mxd"
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd, "Layers")[0]
lyrList = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, "Build*", df)

print "Layer-List  = ", lyrList  ########## A simply list of things
print "Zeroth-Elm  = ", lyrList[0] ######## the zeroth element of the list
print "Zeroth-Type = ", type(lyrList[0])### type of the zeroth element

print "---"

for lyr in lyrList:
    print "Process '" + lyr.name + "' layer"
    if lyr.supports("LABELCLASSES"):
        ### not needed ---> lyr = arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mxd, lyr, df)[0]
        lyr.showLabels = False
        print "\tShow-Labels = " + str(lyr.showLabels)

arcpy.RefreshActiveView()
```

Shown here:
[image]